# Java Applet with 5 text fields and an ok and cancel button

Tags: java, swing, applet

I need to make a Java applet using Swing that has 5 textfields and an ok and a cancel button. Here is my attempt but it doesn't work! What's wrong with it? I haven't added the HTML yet.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class MyApplet extends JApplet {
JButton okButton = new JButton("Okay");
JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
public void init(){
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JTextField f1 = new JTextField("This is a text field");
    field.setEditable(false);
    add(field);
    JTextField f2 = new JTextField("This text is read only");
    field.setEditable(false);
    add(field);
    JTextField f3 = new JTextField("Press okay");
    field.setEditable(false);
    add(field);
    JTextField f4 = new JTextField("or press cancel");
    field.setEditable(false);
    add(field);
    JTextField f5 = new JTextField("Have a nice day!");
    field.setEditable(false);
    add(field);
    okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("Okay");
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(okButton);
    cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println("Okay");
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(cancelButton);

}
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to use the setVisible(true) method? I don't even know if that's a thing for applets...

Comment: Please define `"it doesn't work"`. What is it/isn't it doing? And @WyattLowery, no, that is not needed for applets.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 4):

You're using variables that have never been defined, that don't exist, specifically the `field` variable. Instead, use the variables that you've created, like f1, f2, ...

i.e., change this:

```
JTextField f1 = new JTextField("This is a text field");
field.setEditable(false); // where is field defined??
add(field);               // ditto
```

to this:

```
JTextField f1 = new JTextField("This is a text field");
field.setEditable(f1);
add(f1);
```

similar for the similar problems below.

In the future, please tell us what problems your code is having so we don't have to guess. Show all complete error messages, and describe all misbehaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `field` variable with `f1`, `f2`, et al.. and you should be fine.

For example:

```
JTextField f1 = new JTextField("This is a text field");
f1.setEditable(false);
add(f1);
JTextField f2 = new JTextField("This text is read only");
f2.setEditable(false);
add(f2);
.
.
```